# How to find multiple elements in Array - Javascript ,ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Code:

```
let names= ["Style","List","Raw"];
let results= names.find(x=> x.includes("s");
console.log(results); //
```

How to get the names which contain "s" from the array names,
currently, I am getting only one element as a result but i need all occurrences.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You have to use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) at this context,

```
let names= ["Style","List","Raw"];
let results= names.filter(x => x.includes("s"));
console.log(results); //["List"]
```

If you want it to be case insensitive then use the below code,

```
let names= ["Style","List","Raw"];
let results= names.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().includes("s"));
console.log(results); //["Style", "List"]
```

To make it case in sensitive, we have to make the string's character all to lower case.

Comment: Wonderful __

Comment: i wonder if (dot)filter and (dot)find are identical except for the number of items returned.

Answer (score 6):

Use filter instead of find.

```
let names= ["Style","List","Raw"];
let results= names.filter(x => x.includes("s"));
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 2):

But you can also use forEach() method :

```
var names = ["Style","List","Raw"];
var results = [];
names.forEach(x => {if (x.includes("s") || x.includes("S")) results.push(x)});
console.log(results); // [ 'Style', 'List' ]
```

Or if you prefere :

```
names.forEach(x => {if (x.toLowerCase().includes("s")) results.push(x)});
```

Comment: If you use filter what you are doing in forEach will be done by filter. Filter returns an array whereas forEach won't return anything. So it is better readable :)